# How to Install Package in Xcode via Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm working on a project in Xcode and am attempting to install and use the [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) package via the Swift Package Manager.

I read the [documentation](https://swift.org/package-manager/#conceptual-overview) on SPM, but I don't see instructions on how to invoke the SPM through Xcode.

The examples often refer to calling `$ swift build`. Does this mean that the SPM is only accessible from the command line?
And if so, where exactly am I supposed to create the `Package.swift` file?

I'm reasonably familiar with Xcode, but I don't really understand the meaning of the build settings part of a project, or how Swift modules are used.

EDIT: This question was originally asked for Xcode 7.2, which shipped with Swift 2.1.1. Will gladly accept answers that explain how to do this with current/future versions of Xcode.

Comment: Any update on this now that 7.3 is out?

Comment: @JohnD, Swift Package Manager was not released with Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2.1. It is expected to be released with Swift 3.

Comment: As of today (12/2020), you don't need an xcodeproj (neither to generate-xcodeproj) to build an iOS package. I describe more about that in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758546/can-i-specify-a-platform-target-when-running-swift-test-from-the-cli/65256621#65256621

Answer (score 17):

Swift Package Manager now support generating Xcode project with

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37706061), but this only works when developing a library, or a command line tool. [Not (yet) for (iOS/OS X) graphical application developer](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/swift-4.0.3-RELEASE/Documentation/Usage.md#depending-on-apple-modules):

> Note that at this time the Package Manager has no support for iOS, watchOS, or tvOS platforms.

Note:

- It might not work well if there is a space in your package name, i.e. change "App Store" to "AppStore".

Comment: With the release of Swift 3 and Xcode 8 has this changed?

Comment: @zirinisp It still works for me, with Xcode 8 stable (updated today) on El Capitan.

Comment: it works great when you are use Mac Xcode for Linux developing

Answer (score 13):

At present, to use the Swift Package Manager aka SPM, you need to install the *development* version of Swift 2.2 provided by Apple [here](https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift). Xcode 7.2 shipped with Swift 2.1.1 and does not work with the SPM unless Swift 2.2-dev is installed.

You can compile with Swift 2.2-dev but you will need to do the build of CryptoSwift on the command line using `swift build`. When the library and modulemaps are built, you can drag and drop them into Xcode 7.2 using the Finder. SPM puts the required files into a `.build` directory. But Xcode 7.2 needs to be started with the *alternate toolchain*. This can be done from the command-line using `xcrun launch-with-toolchain /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain` You should be able to `import` from the modules/libraries built with the SPM.

Note though, that you cannot submit iOS apps to the Store at the moment that have been built with the 2.2 *development* version. You can build/run/test things generally without problem, although Playgrounds are not functional and there can be Xcode issues with the debugger.

Comment: All of the above is correct... I would recommend waiting (hopefully not very long) for XCode 7.3 to drop which has better integration with the Swift tool chain.

Answer (score 2):

June 4th, 2019 update. Swift 5 and SPM 5 has added this support and Xcode 11 integrates with SPM.