# Xcode No such module: 'PackageDescription'

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, package-managers

I am extremely confused.

I am trying to import NDHpple into my Swift project so I can parse HTML easily.

I read that you have to use the Swift package manager. Well, so I updated Xcode to 8.1 and verified that I am now using it, as well as Swift 3.0.1.

I copied in the `Package.swift` and when I try to execute my code in Xcode I get this error:

`No such module: 'PackageDescription'`

Can anybody help me? I have searched google and stack but there is literally NOTHING on this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323239/how-to-install-package-in-xcode-via-swift-package-manager ?

Answer (score 0):

It Might sound a bit weird but I added:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
```

in the first line of the file and worked.